# Solve the Sturm-Liouville problem: $xy'' + (1 − x)y' + \lambda y = 0 = (e^{-x^2}y')' + \lambda e^{-x} y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

Consider the singular Sturm-Liouville problem

$$xy'' + (1 − x)y' + \lambda y = 0 = (e^{-x^2}y')' + \lambda e^{-x} y$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0}|y(x)|< \infty, \hspace{0.4cm} \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{y(x)}{x^k} < \infty \hspace{0.5cm} \text{for some positive integer k}$$

Show that the eigenvalues of this problem are $\lambda_n = n$, $n=0,1,2,...$ And the corresponding eigenfunctions are the Laguerre polynomials $L_n (x)$.

**Definition:**
The Laguerre polynomial of order $n$ can be defined as follows:
$$L_n (x) = \frac{e^x}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^n e^{-x})$$
That after developing is of the form:
$$L_n (x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^{k} \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k!}x^k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^{k} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!k!}x^k}$$

*More information about Laguerre polynomials [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials)*

I understand and know that one of the main conditions for posting a question to this community is to attach at least one attempted solution or proof of the problem raised. However, I have spent hours trying to solve this problem, but all my attempts have been unsuccessful, so, feeling frustrated I decided to share this problem with this community with the purpose of knowing a possible solution on this exercise instead of posting alongside this problem futile attempts.

I apologize for my inability to attach any coherent attempt on this Sturm-Liouville problem and welcome any help.

Comment: Did you try "plugging in" the eigenfunctions suggested in the question?

Comment: @daruma  Yes, I did. I tried, but my biggest difficulty is finding the eigenvalues of the problem. I'm familiar with constant coefficient problems, however this problem is very different for me. Can you give me details for this problem please?

Comment: $(e^{-x^2}y')'=e^{-x^2}y''-2xe^{-x^2}y'$ does not seem to jibe with what you have.